# Linear acceleration, gravity, and flipping 180° to slow down

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, rocket-science, propulsion

In The Expanse ships use linear acceleration for gravity with the decks placed perpendicular to the thrust vector, this creating a "floor."

When it comes time to decelerate a ship would need to turn 180° and begin burning in the opposite direction. Is the ship's "floor" now a "ceiling?"

I have tried to think through this and can see it both ways. The "floor" is still the side with the thrust pushing against it, but the motion is now in reverse. Is that right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's warm up with an easier thought experiment: if the ship had a thruster on each end and decelerated by turning one off and the other on, what would happen to the passengers? They'd feel the direction of gravity reverse, so the "floor" and "ceiling" either side of them would swap roles.

But in your thought experiment, the ship rotates and keeps using the same thruster. So while the direction of artificial gravity still reverses, the relative positions of the "floor" and "ceiling" swap, and so the floor is still the floor.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it makes the scenario very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If the ship is accelerating in the $\hat a$ direction as seen from a non-accelerating frame of reference, then the people moving with the ship would say there is a pseudo-force acting on them in the $-\hat a$ direction. The direction of the velocity is irrelevant, all that matters is the direction of the acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

*(Not a physics expert, but saw the question moved here)*

The small ships appear to function like the current rockets and old shuttles.
The floor would be perpendicular to the main thrusters. Once thrust stops, everything continues forward with momentum. There would be no 'floor' at this point. People would 'float' relative to the vessel, while still moving forward at high speed.
When they approach arrival, or need to slow down, small control thrusters flip the ship by 180 degrees. The main thrusters are now facing the opposite direction from when the mission began. Momentum continues to take the vessel towards its target, people are still floating.
Then the main thrusters are activated, decelerating the vessel. The people get forced against the floor, the same floor as during the acceleration phase.

So no, the floor does not become the ceiling, because the entire vessel flips over. When any force (acceleration or deceleration) is applied from the main thrusters, it forces people to the same floor. You will never be in a situation where you look up, and see foot prints on the ceiling.

Maybe if you were looking at if from a different perspective then you could explain that --> direction is currently the ceiling, then the vessel flips, and now <-- direction is the ceiling, so 'the floor has become the ceiling' but that is more of a semantic/language issue.

Answer (score 0):

The force on a person due to the "floor" must be in the same direction as the acceleration as shown in the diagrams below.

[image]

If the rotation by $180^\circ$ had not happened then during the slowing down phase the person would have had to, either hang on to the floor, desk etc, or would have moved so that what was the "ceiling" before was now providing to necessary force to produce the acceleration.